# Generalized Chi squared distribution

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

What is the distribution of $Y Y^\top$ if $Y \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ is a generic multivariate gaussian vector?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution

Comment: It is called a (noncentral) Wishart distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution